# Is it consistent with ZFC that $2^{\aleph_0}$ is a fixed point of the aleph function?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Is it consistent with ZFC that $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_{2^{\aleph_0}}$?

Comment: It is consistent with ZFC+an inaccessible $\kappa$, just by forcing to add $\kappa$ many cohen reals to make $\mathfrak c$ weakly inaccessible

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti: Where is the relevance of the inaccessible, though?

Comment: @Asaf It's definitely not needed as spaceisdarkgreen's answers now shows, I should have realized that the same argument works by replacing the inaccessible $\kappa$ with a fixed point $\kappa$, making $\mathfrak c$ weakly inaccessible is way overkill

Comment: @Alessandro But I think it is worth pointing out that weak inaccessibility is not an obstacle to the size of the continuum): It is consistent (from appropriate large cardinals) that the continuum is weakly Mahlo, and even much more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is consistent. The standard Cohen forcing allows you to set the continuum to anything with uncountable cofinality, and it is cardinal-preserving, so will preserve the property of being an aleph fixed point. So you can set it to any aleph fixed point that has uncountable cofinality, e.g. the $\omega_1$-st aleph fixed point.